# Javascript : Check if RadGrid item is in Edit mode

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radgrid

Iam using a telerik **RadGrid** and I want to check if **GridDataItem** is in edit mode

Using ***javascript*** .

I can handle this using VB but I want to do it on Client Side.

If anyone can tell me also *how to loop through all Items in the Grid and get selected item*

using JavaScript.

I'm stuck Here .. Any Help Please ... I will be grateful.

**2)** I have a problem with OnCommand function in Javascript

I have a ***commandItemTemplate*** in radgrid.

and I add a client event: `<ClientEvents OnCommand="OnCommand" />`

Function:  `function OnCommand(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_commandName() == 'EditSelected') {
            ....}`

The OnCommand doesn't fire on any of the commands in the ***CommandItemTemplate***
, on the other hand , it fires on other commands like (Edit,Update,Delete,...).

I don't know why??  I need Help Please.

Comment: have you converted this object to js? or is that done and you're wondering how to loop through it?

Comment: Can you help me in the second problem I mentioned..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-getting-familiar-with-client-side-api.html)? Using [get_editItems()](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-gridtableview-get-edititems.html) should do the trick

```
function getTableViewEditedItems() {
    var masterTable = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
    //get all edited GridDataItems from the current table view that are in edit mode
    var editedItemsArray = masterTable.get_editItems();
}
```